# Dereferencing pointers in a golang text/template

Tags: pointers, go, go-templates

Inside a golang [template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) when simply outputting values it seems that pointers are automatically dereferenced. When `.ID` is a pointer to an `int`,

`{{.ID}}` outputs `5`

But when I try to use it in a pipeline, `{{if eq .ID 5}}` I get an error.

`executing "mytemplate" at <eq .ID 5>: error calling eq: invalid type for comparison`

How do I do a dereference of a pointer inside a template pipeline?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to register a custom function which dereferences the pointer, so you can compare the result to whatever you want to or do anything else with it.

For example:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "Deref": func(i *int) int { return *i },
    }).Parse(src))
    i := 5
    m := map[string]interface{}{"ID": &i}
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

const src = `{{if eq 5 (Deref .ID)}}It's five.{{else}}Not five: {{.ID}}{{end}}`
```

Output:

```
It's five.
```

Alternatively you could use a different custom function which would take a pointer and a non-pointer, and do the comparision, e.g.:

```
    "Cmp":   func(i *int, j int) bool { return *i == j },
```

And calling it from the template:

```
{{if Cmp .ID 5}}It's five.{{else}}Not five: {{.ID}}{{end}}
```

Output is the same. Try these on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/334xnBtr59).